# get pdf data automatically after drawing (core Plot)

Tags: core-plot

I have a process that collected data.
at specific intervals I need to create graphs and send them to a different process as pdf data.
I gather the data, create the points and I call [graph reloadData].
The problem is:
when will the drawing be finished so I can collect the data using:
 NSData * pdfData = [graph dataForPDFRepresentationOfLayer];?
I can call it with a delay after the reload data but it is a bit fishy.
Is there a notification/function to override to know when the drawing is complete?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No need for a delay. `-dataForPDFRepresentationOfLayer` will make sure the data is up-to-date and render the graph into an offscreen drawing context.